# Why My form submit button send ne to [httpget] action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, data-annotations

I'm Using following Actions and trying to change the Url Of my browser, but when page loaded then first time get method works good. When i try to save (i.e try to post form) then it again sends me on GET action. What Should I do?

```
[Route("Edit-Admin-{id}"),HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(string id)
{
  // Some Code
} 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(AdminViewModel model)
{
   // Some Code
}
```

And in RouteConfig.cs

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `form` tag?

Comment: You need to add the route attribute on the httpPost `[Route("Edit-Admin-{id}")` like you have it now, on the httpGet

Comment: this is my form tag 
<form action="/Edit-Admin-2" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">